# May be too much carbonation on the way

Tags: carbonation, priming, priming-sugar

Bottled up a fig-gose a week ago, and figured I would try one last night just for kicks.  Big hiss and and about a 1 inch head.  Plenty of carbonation now, but it is still 'young' carbonation (big, rough bubbles, etc).  A little worried about bottle bombs or gushers.  Can/should anything be done?  Move them to a cooler part of the house?  The priming calcuator I used has an input for ambient temp, which I put in at 65 degrees (though my house has been closer to 68).  I don't have a chamber for specific temp control (next on the list!)

Here are some stats:
-used corn sugar

-4.75 gallons

-used a berliner weisse as the style into the calculator, which I believe carbs to 3.45 volumes CO2 (since there is not one for gose, but the style should be on the effervescent side)

-OG of 1.060, FG of 1.015

6.8oz corn sugar

I guess in short, if it is carbed to my liking, should i try to crash it down as best as possible to halt the yeast?

Comment: how much corn sugar did you use and how did you add it?

Comment: The temperature parameter for calculating priming sugar addition refers to the peak temperature reached by the fermenting beer. If you aren't measuring temps during fermentation, you could approximate with ambient temperature +5 F.

Comment: I commend you for brewing a Gose.  But putting fig in it??? I'd like to see that recipe and when were the figs added.  Also is it possible your fig addition contributed sugars that you didn't ferment out.  Could be a source of extra carbonation.

Comment: @brewchez, yeah it was a stretch.  Added 12oz pureed fresh figs to the last 5 minutes of the boil.  Would have probably made more sense to add to the secondary, particularly since the style is sometimes served with a fruit syrup.  The final product is a bit cidery, but very drinkable and very interesting.  Going to take some to my homebrew meeting this sunday and get some non-biased reviews....

Comment: @mdma I wasn't aware that this site required me to 'accept' answers, but per your request, I have gone to my threads and done so.

Comment: @brewchez, this beer is growing on me. A few BJCP's in my HB club actually said it was a very close representation of the style. What throws/threw me off was an intense passion fruit/sweet nose that doesn't come through as much in the taste. Overall though, I think this will be a great beer for the summer. Not typically a huge fruit fan, but this might be a good style to experiment with some other fruits. Mosher pretty much says everything sucks except raspberries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be fine. Leave it a another week, and move to a slightly cooler area if you're concerned - since you're already a week in, it won't affect the final carbonation. So long as you distributed the priming sugar evenly (e.g. add to bottling bucket first).

The big hiss and large bubbles is because the CO2 hasn't yet reached equilibrium throughout the bottle - there's more CO2 pressure in the headspace than in the beer. At an ambient temp of 68F, the CO2 takes many days to enter into solution. Since 1 week has passed, most if not all the CO2 has been produced by the yeast, but not yet dissolved - the remaining week is waiting for the CO2 to dissolve into the beer. So you can move them to a cooler part of the house if you're worried about the pressure.

However, the priming sugar calculators - temperature is usually serving temperature, not the temperature that the bottle ferments at. If you plan to store and serve your beer cold, say 43F/6C, then you'll end up with closer to 4.0 volumes. But I don't think that will be too bad for the beer. I don't know about gose, but Berliner Weiss is fine at this level of carbonation.

Comment: also, here is the calculator I use regularly:

http://www.tastybrew.com/calculators/priming.html